# Prediction score in glmnet package r

Tags: r, cross-validation, glmnet

Having the following code from glmnet package:

```
library(glmnet)
set.seed(12345)
fit = glmnet(x , y ,family = "cox", maxit = 1000)
cv.fit = cv.glmnet(x , y ,family = "cox", maxit = 1000)
```

And then predicting the scores as follows:

```
risk.fit = predict(fit, newdata ,s= cv.fit$lambda.min)
risk.cv = predict(cv.fit, newdata )
```

I expected to observe risk.fit and risk.cv exactly the same. But this is not true. Though they are nearly 100 percent correlated. Isn't it correct that the cross validation is done to help finding the min lambda? If so, the predicted scores from the fitted model with "s" equal to min lambda should be the same as the predicted scores from cross validation.
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually more of a programming question but here is the answer to your concern.  If you look at the source code for the S3 method for `cv.glmnet` objects (i.e. `predict.cv.glmnet`) you will see the following:

```
function (object, newx, s = c("lambda.1se", "lambda.min"), ...) 
{ 
... 
some other code
...
}
```

The key point here is that when you call predict on a `cv.glmnet` object you aren't passing the `lamda.min` but actually the `lamda.1se` which is the largest value of lamda that is within 1 standard error of the minimum.  If you pass both then you should find the outputs to be the same.

```
risk.fit <- predict(fit, newdata, s = cv.fit$lambda.1se)
risk.cv <- predict(cv.fit, newdata)
```

This is done based on the principal if all things are held equal, one should almost always choose the simpler model.

If you really want to just use the minimum `lambda` you will need to explicitly say so.